# How to hook up Terraform to create Cloud Build Triggers that pull from a private bitbucket Repo In the GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I am setting up a terraform plan in order to create a cloud build trigger in the google cloud provider. However the steps outlined in the terraform documentation are for public git repositories. When I tried hooking up a private bitbucket repository I got a "repo not found" error.

```
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "cloudbuild-trigger" {
  trigger_template {
    branch_name = "staging"
    repo_name = "BITBUCKET_TEAM_NAME/repo_name"
    dir = "site_dir"
  }

  filename = "cloudbuild.yml"
}
```

Comment: Are you specifying the Bitbucket credentials someplace else?

Comment: @JimRedmond I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about bitbucket credentials for the google cloud build trigger module.

Comment: It's a private repo. If you don't pass some sort of authentication for it then you won't be able to access it.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to implement this or where I can find more information. I can't seem to get the right search to hone in on this. That would be very helpfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide access for a private repository — BitBucket provides an [App Password](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html).

After creating such password with “Repository Read” permission you can form a URI with your App Password to the provide access for your repository.

For example: `https://YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/YOUR-TEAM/YOUR-REPO.git` and that URI will provide access for reading your repository without asking password. Of course, you must understand the consequences of credentials exposure.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried the URI in place of repo_name. Did it work for you @Pablo Marti Cordero ?

Answer (score 2):

**repo_name** expects the name of the Cloud Source Repository not the bitbucket repo. Initially from the UI, we can connect cloud build to our bitbucket repo(private).

In the setup, we can opt to mirror our repo in Cloud Source. We can then provide the Cloud Source repo name ti terraform. In this case, We don't have to pass any bitbucket credentials to terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Fully featured Cloud Build triggers for BitBucket which react to events and show their results in BitBucket like you can create them in the UI or via REST API are not yet supported by the GCP Terraform provider.

For external BitBucket servers there is an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/11499) to add this functionality.